# request_html not returning/rendering whole web page

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, request, htmlsession

I am trying to parse a google shopping page and I am trying to do it faster than selenium. I stumbled across request_html and it's been working pretty well. I have almost everything I need from it except one element it isn't parsing from the page. If you go to [this](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1866&bih=1043&tbm=shop&q=desk&tbs=mr:1,price:1,ppr_min:,ppr_max:,avg_rating:None) google shopping page you will notice that you can hover over some of the product images and see a second one. I am parsing the information from each product but when it comes to both images for some reason request_html is only retrieving the second(hovered) image and not the first(main) one. I have attached my code below I have been trying to find a good way to represent the output of request_html to show what it IS retrieving but I haven't found a way for it to print in a readable manner. To my knowledge request_html can render javascript on pages and in my case, it is just weird that it is getting everything but the first image. I have viewed the 'inspect' part of the page to get the HTML and the image's div class that I am trying to get is '.gOenxf'. **Why is request_html not rendering the first image of each product?**

```
for google_post in google_initiate(request):
    #  parse what is needed


def google_initiate(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        url = 'https://www.google.com/search?biw=1866&bih=1043&tbm=shop&q=desk&tbs=mr:1,price:1,ppr_min:,ppr_max:,avg_rating:None'
    session = HTMLSession()
    response = session.get(url)
    print(response.html)
    google_parsed = response.html.find('.sh-dgr__gr-auto.sh-dgr__grid-result')
    response.close()
    session.close()
    return google_parsed
```

**UPDATE:**

```
import requests
from requests_html import HTMLSession

for google_post in google_initiate(request):
    post_website = 'Google'
    post_parse_page = google_initiate.google_parse_page
    try:
        post_title = google_post.find('.Xjkr3b', first=True).text
    except:
        post_title = ''

    try:
        post_url = str(google_post.find('.xCpuod'))
        post_url = 'https://www.google.com' + post_url[post_url.find("href='") + len("href='"):post_url.rfind("'")]
    except:
        post_url = ''

    try:
        post_second_website = google_post.find('.aULzUe.IuHnof', first=True).text
        if 'Amazon' in post_second_website or 'eBay' in post_second_website or 'Walmart' in post_second_website or 'AliExpress' in post_second_website or 'Craigslist' in post_second_website or 'Facebook Marketplace' in post_second_website or 'Oodle' in post_second_website:
            post_second_website = ''
    except:
        post_second_website = ''

    try:
        post_second_url = str(google_post.find('.shntl'))
        post_second_url = post_second_url[post_second_url.find("href='/url?url=") + len("href='/url?url="):post_second_url.rfind("'")]
        if '%' in post_second_url:
            post_second_url = post_second_url.split('%')[0]
    except:
        post_second_url = ''

    try:
        post_second_image_url = str(google_post.find('img'))
        if 'encrypted' in post_second_image_url:
            post_second_image_url = post_second_image_url[post_second_image_url.find("data-image-src='") + len("data-image-src='"):post_second_image_url.rfind('')]
        else:
            post_second_image_url = NO_IMAGE
    except:
        post_second_image_url = ''

    try:
        post_price = google_post.find('.a8Pemb.OFFNJ', first=True).text
        post_price = str(post_price.split()[0])
        try:  string first
            if '.' not in post_price:
                post_price = post_price + '.00'
            elif len(post_price.split('.')[1]) == 1:
                post_price = post_price + '0'
            elif len(post_price.split('.')[1]) == 0:
                post_price = post_price + '00'
            post_sort_by = post_price.replace(',', '')  
            post_sort_by = float(post_sort_by.split('$')[1]) 
        except:
            post_price = 'n/a'
            post_sort_by = ''
    except:
        post_price = 'n/a'
        post_sort_by = ''

    try:
        post_rating = google_post.find('.Rsc7Yb', first=True).text
    except:
        post_rating = ''

    try:
        post_rating_quantity = google_post.find('.NzUzee', first=True).text
        post_rating_quantity = str(post_rating_quantity.split()[1])
    except:
        post_rating_quantity = ''

    try:
        post_image_url = str(google_post.find('.gOenxf'))
        if 'encrypted' in post_image_url:
            post_image_url = post_image_url[post_image_url.find("src='") + len("src='"):post_image_url.rfind("'")]
        else:
            post_image_url = NO_IMAGE
    except:
        post_image_url = ''

    google_final_postings.append((post_title, post_url, post_price, post_image_url, post_rating, post_rating_quantity, post_website, post_second_website, post_second_url, post_second_image_url, post_parse_page, post_sort_by))







def google_initiate(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        url = 'https://www.google.com/search?biw=1866&bih=1043&tbm=shop&q=desk&tbs=mr:1,price:1,ppr_min:,ppr_max:,avg_rating:None'
    session = HTMLSession()
    response = session.get(url)
    google_parsed = response.html.find('.sh-dgr__gr-auto.sh- 
    dgr__grid-result')
    print(google_parsed)
    response.close()
    session.close()
    return google_parsed
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete working sample to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @SystemSigma_ Thank you for your response. I added the additional code in the original post under "UPDATE:". It should be everything needed but if not let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the content in question is dynamically injected by Javascript, you need to call `response.html.render()` before seeking the element.

```py
def google_initiate(request):
    form = SearchForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        url = 'https://www.google.com/search?biw=1866&bih=1043&tbm=shop&q=desk&tbs=mr:1,price:1,ppr_min:,ppr_max:,avg_rating:None'
    session = HTMLSession()
    response = session.get(url)
    response.html.render()
    print(response.html)
    google_parsed = response.html.find('.sh-dgr__gr-auto.sh-dgr__grid-result')
    response.close()
    session.close()
    return google_parsed
```

See example in [official docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/#javascript-support).

Comment: I have seen .render() in some of the documentation I have looked at but every time I went to implement it I couldn't get around the error I was getting. I tried it again and got the same error "'HTMLResponse' object has no attribute 'render'". I can't figure out what is wrong.

Comment: I typo'd - it's `response.html.render()` (answer updated). Try that

Comment: I have not integrated your new code and my original problem is gone. However, now I am getting this "There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-3'." error and don't know exactly what to make of it.

Comment: Correction "I have now"

Comment: @RussellHertel It sounds like you're using threads in code not visible here. Only some objects & libraries are thread-safe, others are not. Check their docs for details. If you need help with that you'd need to post a separate question. I've answered this one.